# Displaying random questions in an application

Tags: android, random, viewflipper

I am developing an application which involves a quiz in it. I have used a viewflipper for displaying question, as i press the next button it flips to next question. However, I wish to display these questions randomly. I have parsed an xml and displayed the questions n its options !

Comment: and do you have a more detailed question as well as code for us?

Comment: How are you displaying the questions and answers? Are you storing them somehwhere ?

Comment: I am getting them from the xml....have a pojo class which has a setter n getter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all your questions stored in `array` or some data structure e.g. `ArrayList`

You need to define a single random object **only once** in your activity

e.g.

```
Random random = new Random();
```

Get the next question index:

```
int nextQuestionIndex = random.nextInt(n); // where n is the total number of questions
```